# Multiple IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH excluding

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

[Please see the following pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syZwG.png)

**I have a list of items**:
Apples, oranges, tea, kiwi, grapes

**A list of states** (we all know)

**And a list of 3 stores**.

Store 3 (for example) can deliver apples, and grapes. It can also deliver oranges ONLY if on the cell they are with tea or kiwi. They CANNOT deliver items to FL, NV, SD.

How can I create a formula for this?

I also though of using SUBSTITUTE or AND's but I can't figure my way through this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you!

```
    =IF(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,"apples,oranges,bananas")), 
         NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,"kiwi")))), "Stuff2", 
     IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,"coffee,chicken,tea,kiwi")),"Stuff1", ""))
```

Comment: Seems it gives an error because of the amount of arguments. I'll redo my question a bit more specific.